# What is the best way of typing these windows Commands in CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

```
shell > mysql -uroot -p 

shell > mysql -u root -p
```

Both commands work fine in windows CMD. But I have a doubt about making spaces between some keywords.(between -u and root) Should I keep a space between -u and root(example : -u{space}root)  or -uroot ?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In general, this depends on the implementation of the command you are using. Many programs that use UNIX-Style options allow both, but some do not. You will notice that: The command will fail, complaining about an unknown argument.

If you think that there could be a collision with a different option, consult the program's manual. By collision I mean, for example, if MySQL had two different options `-u` and `-uroot`. This is a problem that actually never occured to me, but if I call programs from shell scripts, I prefer writing the parameter separately, like `-u root`.